# Получения значения по ключу в HashMap,LinkedHashMap,Map

Tags: java, java-8

Всем привет,у меня закрался довольно интересный вопрос в ходе роботы с Map. Итак, у меня есть массив который заполняется случайными числами, позже я сравниваю эти числа с другим массивом ( также заполнятся случайными числами ), если числа совпадают True, иначе False.Вопрос: я хочу посчитать чего больше True или False ( +1 если совпадает условия ).

P.s в ходе написания вопроса я решил данную задачу, решил оставить вопрос, для тех кому ( возможно ) понадобится. **Но также буду рад вашим вариантам решения задачи. Возможно кто-то знает способ который лучше/быстрее/эффективней решает задачу**

Код:

```
package Collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class lalaalal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numbers ;
        Integer randomNumber;
        ArrayList<String> arrayListmain = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayListmain2 = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<Integer,String> linkedHashMapArray= new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // randomNumber =20+ (int) ( Math.random() * 80 );
            randomNumber =1+ (int) ( Math.random() * 10 );

            arrayListmain.add(randomNumber.toString());

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListmain.size(); i++) {

            randomNumber =1+ (int) ( Math.random() * 10 );
            arrayListmain2.add(randomNumber.toString());

        }
        int countNumberFalse =0;
        int countNumberTrue = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to Create second array and Compare with first");


        

        System.out.println(arrayListmain + "First Array\n");

        System.out.println(arrayListmain2 + "Second Array\n");

        


        for (int  i =0  ; i < arrayListmain.size(); i++) {

            

            if (arrayListmain.get(i).equals(arrayListmain2.get(i))){
                linkedHashMapArray.put(i,"True");
            }
            if (!arrayListmain.get(i).equals(arrayListmain2.get(i))){
                linkedHashMapArray.put(i,"False");
            }

        }

        System.out.println("linkedHashMapArray: "+linkedHashMapArray);
        System.out.println("Size:"+linkedHashMapArray.size());

        // Собственно то самое получения значения ( value ), сначала я добавляю значения в linkedHashMapArray (
        // циклом выше ) позже при linkedHashMapArray.get достаю значения по номеру ( который
        // я циклом выше добавляю ) ключа и сравниваю его с значения String

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListmain.size(); i++) {
//                                System.out.println("I="+i);

            if (linkedHashMapArray.get(i)== "True"){


                countNumberTrue +=1;

            }
            else if(linkedHashMapArray.get(i)== "False") {

                countNumberFalse +=1;

            }


        }
//
        System.out.println("True:"+countNumberTrue +"False:"+countNumberFalse);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, есть способы решить данную задачу более правильно.

1. Вам для решения задачи не нужно использовать список из строк. Вы работаете с целыми числами - объявите ArrayList и сразу отпадет необходимость преобразовывать числа в строки.
2. Для генерации целых чисел вместо Math.random() можно использовать nextInt() класса java.util.Random.
3. Для подсчета числа совпадающих элементов достаточно использовать один цикл и переменную-счетчик.

Прикрепляю свой вариант для примера:

```
final int NUM_OF_ELEMENTS = 100;

ArrayList<Integer>
    firstList = new ArrayList<>(),
    secondList = new ArrayList<>();

Random random = new Random();

// Заполнение коллекций случайными числами
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++){
    firstList.add(random.nextInt(10) + 1);
    secondList.add(random.nextInt(10) + 1);
}

// Подсчет количества совпадений
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS; i++){
    if(firstList.get(i).equals(secondList.get(i))) count++;
}

// Вывод результата:
System.out.println(
    String.format("Совпало: %s, не совпало: %s", count, NUM_OF_ELEMENTS - count)
);
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо.